# flutter,dart - parameter from onpressed properties

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-onpressed

I want to pass parameters onto the  'onpressed'

- :)  == official syntax
- :(  == get a void error
- : p  == is the trick I wrote, which doesn't give me an editor error,
  but a console error  with  `setstate() after dispose()` message

**Is there a way to pass parameters to methods in onpressed?**

```
// :) onPressed: (){},
// :) onPressed: _methodName,
// :( onPressed: _methodName(param),
// :p onPressed: (){_methodName(param)},

onPressed: () {
    var docId = _dataList[idx].documentID;
    setState(() { ... });
    print('delete complite');
),
```

cf. :( error img 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfHpu.png

Comment: The cleanest is probably `onPressed: () => _methodName(param),`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the image you posted, you should do

```
onPressed: () => _clickDeleteIcon(_dataList[idx].documentId),
```